# android mediaplayer bacgroung loading

Tags: android

how can i load a file into mediaplayer while showing a splash screen in the foregroung ,i mean after splash sceen i want to display video on the screen directly without wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using VideoView, follow these steps:
1) show your splash screen
2)

```
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

3) turn off splash screen and play video -

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
// splash dismiss here
videoView.start();
}
```